# Validation failed: grouping expressions sequence is empty

Tags: sql

I want to add 2 columns which calculate costs based on price and quantity.
The quantity is calculated from a number of equipment with the count function then I calculate the costs by multiplying the quantity and the prices.

But I have this error:

`Validation failed grouping expressions sequence is empty, and a.refr_comm' is not an aggregate function. Wrap (count(a.idnt_eqpm) AS quantite, (a.prix_pump_ht * CAST(count(a.idnt_eqpm) AS DOUBLE)) AS cout_total, (CAST(a.prx_tot_net AS BIGINT) * count(a.idnt_eqpm)) AS CA)`

Here is my initial data :

| refr_comm | idnt_eqpm | name_eqpm | prce_pump | prce_tot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -J-NRJ-YONDEZ | 12773202 | IPHONE 12 APPLE | 800 | 859 |
| -J-NRJ-YONDEZ | 12773202 | IPHONE 12 APPLE | 800 | 859 |
| -J-NRJ-YONDT4A | 12773188 | SAMSUNG S22 | 550 | 599 |

And I want this display :

| refr_comm | idnt_eqpm | name_eqpm | prce_pump | prce_tot | count_eqpm | ca | total_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -J-NRJ-YONDEZ | 12773202 | IPHONE 12 APPLE | 800 | 859 | 2 | 1600 | 1718 |
| -J-NRJ-YONDT4A | 12773188 | SAMSUNG S22 | 550 | 599 | 1 | 550 | 599 |

800 * 2 = 1600

859 * 2 = 1718

Here is my query :

```
SELECT 
    refr_comm,
    idnt_eqpm, 
    name_eqpm,
    prce_pump,
    prce_tot,  
    count(idnt_eqpm) as count_eqpm, 
    prce_tot  * count(idnt_eqpm) AS CA,
    prce_pump * count(idnt_eqpm) AS total_cost 
                    
FROM (
    SELECT 
        refr_comm,
        idnt_eqpm, 
        name_eqpm,
        prce_pump,
        prce_tot  
        
    FROM cat_fa_ca_equipement_bte    
) a
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For future Questions always provide your DBMS in your question.

The error message itselfs directly tells you, that your query is missing a GROUP BY CLAUSE (or elements within that clause).

[Link to GROUP BY Explanation by w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

I would recommend reading this or another tutorial about the topic before reading the solution to your question.

---

Solution (with changed fields names):

```sql
SELECT
ref,
article_id,
name,
price_net,
price_gross,
count(*) as "count_sales",
sum(price_net) as "sum_net",
sum(price_gross) as "total_cost"
FROM articles
GROUP BY ref, article_id, name, price_net, price_gross
```

Result:

| ref | article_id | name | price_net | price_gross | count_sales | sum_net | total_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YONDEZ | 12773202 | Iphone 12 Apple | 800 | 859 | 2 | 1600 | 1718 |
| YONDT4A | 12773188 | Samsung S22 | 550 | 599 | 1 | 550 | 599 |

[db<>fiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/RiAKOtaE)

I've removed the unnecessary subquery from your try and simply added the GROUP BY CLAUSE for all fields that don't use a aggregation function.
Instead of counting the price fields and multiplying them with the value, you can simply sum them becuase 3 * x = x + x + x

Comment: I tried this solution but I have a quantity equal to 1 on all lines.

Comment: Then there is some column with unique values for every row within your dataset that isn't shown in your example data.
My guess would be to  refr_comm.
Learn about group by and then try, by adjusting the query, to find the column which has unique values per row.